# Оптимизация png и jpg

Tags: png, jpeg

Какими сервисом вы пользуетесь , что бы максимально сжать , но без потери качества JPG и PNG файлы ? И главное , чтобы файлы оставались в исходных папках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно неплохой инструмент - [FileOptimizer](http://nikkhokkho.sourceforge.net/static.php?page=FileOptimizer).
Последовательно применяет к файлам несколько плагинов оптимизации.
Более подробно про схему работы и дополнительные настройки на русском можно прочитать [тут](https://datbaze.ru/soft/fileoptimizer-optimizatsiya-izobrazheniy-i-drugih-tipov-faylov.html).

Ну, а при первоначальном сохранении PNG в Photoshop, можно использовать плагин [SuperPNG](https://github.com/fnordware/SuperPNG).
Сохраняет изображения, удаляя meta-данные + можно качество при сохранении выбирать.